# How to get an scalable ImageView that is larger than the screen size and can be scrolled vertically and horizontically?

Tags: android, imageview

I have added an ImageView to a FrameLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView inside a relative layout that is inside a ScrollView programmatically. I have added a ScaleGestureDetector, to detect zoom in and zoom out.

```
private void SetTouchListener(ImageView iv)
{
    if (iv != null && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
        iv.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener()
        {
            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.FROYO)
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
            {
                boolean res = mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return res;
            }
        });
    }
}
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener
{
    @Override
    public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        float fscaleX = frmLayoutImage.getScaleX() * detector.getScaleFactor();
        float fscaleY = frmLayoutImage.getScaleY()* detector.getScaleFactor();
        frmLayoutImage.setScaleX(fscaleX);
        frmLayoutImage.setScaleY(fscaleY);
        return true;
    }
}
```

When zooming in the picture gets smaller and is centered, but when zooming out the picture is cropped to the ImageView bounds and can't be scrolled vertically or horizontally. How can I get the ImageView to adjust it's size?

Here is the code

```
private void showBitmap (Bitmap b)
{
    boolean isNew = false;
    if (b!= null)
    {
        if (iv == null)
        {
            iv = new ImageView(context);
            SetTouchListener(iv);

        }

        if (sv == null)
        {
            sv = new HorizontalScrollView(context);

            isNew = true;
        }

        if (frmLayoutImage == null)
        {
            frmLayoutImage = new ScalingFrameLayout(context);
            frmLayoutImage.setClipChildren(false);

            isNew = true;
        }

        b = resizeBM(b);
        iv.setImageBitmap(b);
        if (iv.getParent() == null)
        {
            try
            {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams p = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                p.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                //p.weight = 1.0f;
                iv.setLayoutParams(p);
                iv.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                iv.setClickable(true);
                iv.setFocusable(true);
                iv.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
                {
                    iv.setCropToPadding(false);
                }


                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pold = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) _txtMeaning1.getLayoutParams();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pnew = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                pnew.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, R.id.txtMeaning1);
                pnew.setMargins(pold.leftMargin,pold.topMargin,pold.rightMargin, pold.topMargin);

                sv.setLayoutParams(pnew);
                sv.setFillViewport(true);
                sv.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);
                sv.setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(false);

                FrameLayout.LayoutParams pp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                pp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
                frmLayoutImage.setLayoutParams(pp);


                frmLayoutImage.addView(iv);

                sv.addView(frmLayoutImage);

                rellayoutMain.addView(sv);



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("addImageView",ex.getMessage(),ex);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("ImageView","exists");
        }
        _txtMeaning1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        sv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        frmLayoutImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        String status ="main "+ rellayoutMain.getWidth() + " sv " + sv.getWidth() + " llimg " + frmLayoutImage.getWidth() + " iv " + iv.getWidth();
        lib.setgstatus(status);
    }
}
```

and the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layoutMainParent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="org.de.jmg.learn.MainActivity"
>
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/layoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/layoutButtons"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/rellayoutMain" 
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LayWord"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <org.de.jmg.lib.BorderedTextView
                android:id="@+id/word"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="60px"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal"
                />

            <org.de.jmg.lib.BorderedEditText
                android:id="@+id/edword"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="60px"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:typeface="normal"
                android:visibility="gone" />

          </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout
              android:id="@+id/LayCom"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_below="@+id/LayWord"
              android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <org.de.jmg.lib.BorderedTextView
                android:id="@+id/Comment"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="35px"
                />

            <org.de.jmg.lib.BorderedEditText
                android:id="@+id/edComment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:maxLines="3"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:text="@string/hello_world"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="35px"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <org.de.jmg.lib.BorderedEditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMeaning1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LayCom"
            android:layout_marginTop="120px"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40px"
            >

            <requestFocus android:layout_width="wrap_content" />

        </org.de.jmg.lib.BorderedEditText>

        <org.de.jmg.lib.BorderedEditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMeaning2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtMeaning3"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMeaning1"
            android:layout_marginTop="56px"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40px"
            />

        <org.de.jmg.lib.BorderedEditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMeaning3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtMeaning2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="56px"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:lines="2"
            android:maxLines="20"
            android:minLines="2"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="40px"
            />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButtons" 
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutButtonsInner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnSkip"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="60px"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
                android:text="@string/btnSkip"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:padding="0dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRight"
                android:layout_width="110px"
                android:layout_height="60px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnSkip"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
                android:text="@string/btnRight"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:padding="0dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnView"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="60px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnRight"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
                android:text="@string/btnView"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:padding="0dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnWrong"
                android:layout_width="120px"
                android:layout_height="60px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnView"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
                android:text="@string/btnWrong"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:padding="0dp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
                android:layout_width="100px"
                android:layout_height="60px"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btnWrong"
                android:layout_marginBottom="0px"
                android:text="@string/btnEdit"
                android:textSize="20px"
                android:padding="0dp" />
        </RelativeLayout>    

        <org.de.jmg.lib.BorderedTextView
            android:id="@+id/txtStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textSize="20px" 
            android:layout_below="@+id/layoutButtonsInner"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" 
        />
    </RelativeLayout>           
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

refer this link, it might help.
https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView

you can define default scale size and scroll your image horizontally and vertically